# How to decode this data

Tags: urldecode

I have a field in the DB that is type bytea and this is an example of the data in:
\254\355\000\005sr\000\014java.net.URL\226%76\032\374\344r\003\000\007I\000\010hashCodeI\000\004portL\000\011authorityt\000\022Ljava/lang/String;L\000\004fileq\000~\000\001L\000\004hostq\000~\000\001L\000\010protocolq\000~\000\001L\000\003refq\000~\000\001xp\377\377\377\377\377\377\377\377t\000\021asm.objectweb.orgt\000\013/index.htmlq\000~\000\003t\000\004httppx

I need to convert this data into readable URL, do you know how can I do that? What type of encoding is this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that data is an internal Java format, possibly an object flattened to a stream somehow. Your best bet would be to locate the code that places the data in the database in the first place, and determine what it's using to create those bytes.